# Sequence contains no matching element using ToList() method

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I have a piece of code that should retrieve the result of the SP named "spWebObtenerDatosCobros".

[image: Error i'm getting]

Here's my Keyless entity
[image: Here's my entity]

[image: Stored procedure]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need `IgnoreQueryFilters` on `FromSqlRaw`.

Comment: I have tried removing IgnoreQueryFilters method and still getting same error

Comment: `Sequence contains no elements` this error indicates that there are no elements in the stored procedure you are currently executing that can be returned. According to your Cobros class, you add the NotMapped attribute to all fields, which will cause these fields cannot be generated in theCobros table , and what is the specific content of your stored procedure?

Comment: @YongqingYu I just eddited the post, so you can see what the sp returns.

Comment: @HommyDeJesús, what I need you to provide is the specific content of `spWebObtenerDatosCobros`.